# Python: How can I save the content of several html files, into a html link, from <title> tag?

Tags: python, html, tags, save-as

I have a Python code that works fine for parsing some data on html files. At the end of the code I must save the html files by  tag. For example, I have this 3 html files with 3 titles tags:

```
<title>My name is Prince</title>
<title>I love Madonna</title>
<title>Cars and Candies</title>
```

**Each of them must be save like this:**

```
my-name-is-prince.html
I-love-madonna.html
cars-and-candies.html
```

**So, I already have some SAVE solution for Python, but I don't know how to save by  tag.**

```
try:
    title = re.search('<title.+/title>', html)[0]
    title_content = re.search('>(.+)<', title)[1]
    except:
    pass


with open("my-words.html", "w") as some_file_handle:
    some_file_handle.write(finalString)
```

OR

```
with open('page_323.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(result.text)
```

OR

```
with open("somefilename.txt", "w") as some_file_handle:  
    for line in data: 
        some_file_handle.write(line + "\n")
```

P.S. I have 500 files. The Python code must find each  tag from each html and save each of them into new html.

Comment: Did you already extract title from html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Are you looking for that:

```
# html = """<title>My name is Prince</title>"""

>>> re.search(r'<title>(?P<title>.+)</title>', html).groups('title')[0] \
      .replace(' ', '-').lower()

'my-name-is-prince'
```

---

**Old answer**
If you already extract title from html you can do:

```
title = 'My name is Prince'
filename = f"{title.lower().replace(' ', '-')}.html"

with open(filename, "w") as some_file_handle:
    some_file_handle.write(finalString)
```

Comment: thanks. Yes, is a good option. The problem is that I have 500 files, cannot run each of them for save. The Python code must find each <title> tag from each html and save each of them into html. Not one by one, because this will take a lot of time.

Comment: Do you use BeautifulSoup? How do you parse your html file? Can you share more code especially when you parse data?

Comment: `try:`
       `title = re.search('<title.+/title>', html)[0]`
        `title_content = re.search('>(.+)<', title)[1]`
         `except:`
          `pass`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use beautifulsoup, check this:

```
soup = soup.encode(formatter=UnsortedAttributes()).decode('utf-8')
new_filename = title.get_text() 
new_filename = new_filename.lower()
words = re.findall(r'\w+', new_filename)
new_filename = '-'.join(words)
new_filename = new_filename + '.html'
    print(new_filename)
```

**see the complete code here:**

https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/python-google-translate-beautifulsoup-library-save-title-tag-as-link.html